# nsight VSE debugger error "code patching failed due to lack of code patching memory"

Tags: cuda, nsight

I am having a nsight debug error like following, when I was debugging a cuda kernel using nsight. I have no idea what that means. Looks like something to do with cuFFT. But can anyone give some pointers? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It's a fairly descriptive error message.  Did you try the suggestion: "Please increase Nsight|Options|CUDA|Code Patching Memory and try again" ?

Comment: The demangled version of the kernel is "void __kernelTex<(fftDirection_t)-1>(float2*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, divisor_t, divisor_t, divisor_t, dimStride_t, dimStride_t, dimStride_t, dimStride_t)"  If you don't recognize a kernel with that prototype, it is likely coming from a library that you are using.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I am trying to increase the Patching Memory, but it seems my Nsight does not have that option. I am using Nsight 5.0. I doubt it was something wrong in the cuFFT, the cuda fft library.

Comment: @Nick X Tsui: Please read some [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/nsight/use_memory_checker.htm%3FTocPath%3DDeveloper%2520Tools%7CDesktop%2520Developer%2520Tools%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%25205.0%7CCUDA%2520Debugger%7CAdvanced%2520Topics%7C_____2)

Comment: Regarding this:  " I am trying to increase the Patching Memory, but it seems my Nsight does not have that option. "    Do you have an `Options...` choice on the `Nsight` menu?  I happen to have a machine with nsight 4.7 loaded, and the option is there at Nsight...Options...CUDA...CUDA Debugger...Code Patching Memory Factor.  It is currently set to 2. You would want to increase that number as a test.  If you can't find the option, please be specific about what you see as you traverse through Nsight...Options...CUDA...  etc. You may have to scroll some of the panes up or down to see all options.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks I am reading it.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Yes, talonmies helped, so I guess I will increase the number from 2 to 4 and see what's gonna happen.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I increased the patching code size to 8, the same warning/message still showed. Then I increased the size to 16, and the warning/message went away. Thank you guys.

Comment: @talonmies Thank you.

Comment: Can any of you post the answer here?

Comment: @NickXTsui: It is perfectly OK to post your own answer describing what you did to solve it. You will be able to accept your own answer later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message reported by Nsight cleared indicated, the error is caused by Nsight having insufficient available memory on the device to interactively debug the code you are running. Quoting from the Nsight documentation:

> When the CUDA Memory Checker is enabled, it will consume extra memory
>   on the GPU. If there is not enough patch RAM for the CUDA Debugger, it
>   will give the following error:
>
> ```
> Internal debugger error occurred while attempting to launch "KernelName - CUmodule 0x04e67f10: code patching failed due to lack of code patching memory.
> ```
>
> If this happens, increase the patch RAM factor by going to Nsight >
>   Options > CUDA > Code Patching Memory Factor.
>
> This is a multiplier of the kernel's instruction size, which is added
>   to a base patch RAM size of 64k.
>
> Another option is to disable the shared or global memory checking, in
>   order to use less patch RAM.

The original poster noted that increasing the code patching memory factor from a ratio of 2 to 16 solved the problem.